# sed is to split a line on certain characters and with a extra condition

Tags: sed

How can `sed` split a line on certain characters and with additional condition,
that is after range 30 - 35 characters.

Within a start-end marked block, that's **```** but for start mark followed by word

Characters is `. , space`
if it's space, replaced with newline control character on which otherwise appended

e.g.

````
 ```bash
 hello world hello world hello world hello foo, bar, world hello foo, bar, world
 ```
````

to become

````
```bash
hello world hello world hello world
hello foo, bar, world hello foo, bar,
world
```
````

Farthest i could:

````
sed -E /^```\w/,/^```/{:bloc n; :split s/^.{30,35}[.,[:space:]]/&/;T bloc; p;s/^.{30,35}[.,[:space:]](.*)/\1\n/; b split}' -- FILE
````

which surely far from correct so please sincerely help show the correct path.

Comment: You might want to `man fold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed -E '/```/{n;:a;N;//!ba;s/([^\n]{30,35}[^,. ]*[,.]*) /\1\n/g}' file
````

Populate the pattern space with the required stanza, then globally replace the first space within the required range with a newline.

A variation on the solution would split on the first `,`,`.` or   and still absorb a following space too:

````
sed -E '/```/{n;:a;N;//!ba;s/([^\n]{30,35}[^,. ]*)(([,.]) ?| )/\1\3\n/g}' file
````